# JWT Scala- java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException

Tags: scala, encryption, jwt

I'm trying to create a JWT with JWT Scala using:

```
import pdi.jwt._

...

val claim = s"""{ \"exp\": $oneMinuteFromNow }"""
Jwt.encode(claim, key, JwtAlgorithm.ES512)
```

`key` is a String containing a private key in the form of

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGbMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAjA4GGAAQAmG8JrpLz14+qUs7oxFX0pCoe90Ah
MMB/9ZENy8KZ+us26i/6PiBBc7XaiEi6Q8Icz2tiazwSpyLPeBrFVPFkPgIADyLa
T0fp7D2JKHWpdrWQvGLLMwGqYCaaDi79KugPo6V4bnpLBlVtbH4ogg0Hqv89BVyI
ZfwWPCBH+Zssei1VlgM=
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

But I'm getting:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: encoded key spec not recognized: wrong version for private key info
  at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.util.BaseKeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePrivate(Unknown Source)
  at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.KeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePrivate(Unknown Source)
  at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:366)
  at pdi.jwt.JwtUtils$.parsePrivateKey(JwtUtils.scala:109)
  at pdi.jwt.JwtUtils$.sign(JwtUtils.scala:152)
  at pdi.jwt.JwtUtils$.sign(JwtUtils.scala:159)
  at pdi.jwt.JwtCore$class.encode(Jwt.scala:80)
  at pdi.jwt.Jwt$.encode(Jwt.scala:23)
  at pdi.jwt.JwtCore$class.encode(Jwt.scala:109)
  at pdi.jwt.Jwt$.encode(Jwt.scala:23)
```

I've Googled everything I can think of, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help appreciated!

(above key is not a real key BTW)

Comment: The main thing you're doing wrong is using JWT but how did you generate this key? How do you know it's the right kind of key, formatted correctly, etc?

Comment: The keys I've tested with are valid and in the exact format as the fake key above. Formatting could be part of the problem, however. I'm not sure.

Comment: That doesn't exactly answer my question. How do you know they are valid? What generates them? What consumes them to verify their validity? The exception you've shown is the underlying crypto library complaining about the key.

Comment: I have a working implementation of this in another programming language using the same key. I'm using "ES512" as the algorithm in both implementations. My hunch is it's a formatting or encoding problem of some sort.

Comment: The details of how you generate the key and what you are able to verify it with is what matters. Then you can check if it's a format bouncycastle handles.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this working.

`openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp521r1 -noout -out ec512-key-pair.pem`

Is the command I ued to generate the key. The code to sign the JWT:

```
object JwtGen {

  def generateToken(keyPath: String) : String = {
    if (keyPath.isEmpty) throw new java.io.IOException("keyPath is empty!")
    val claim = s"""{ \"exp\": $oneMinuteFromNow }"""
    Jwt.encode(claim, encodeKey(keyPath), JwtAlgorithm.ES512)
  }

  private def oneMinuteFromNow: Long = {
    (System.currentTimeMillis / 1000) + 60
  }

  private def encodeKey(keyPath: String): PrivateKey = {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider)
    val parser = new PEMParser(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(keyPath)))
    val pemObject = Option(parser.readObject)
    pemObject match {
      case Some(kp: PEMKeyPair) => convertFormat(kp)
      case _ => throw new java.io.IOException(s"cannot parse pem file $keyPath")
    }
  }

  private def convertFormat(pemKeyPair: PEMKeyPair): PrivateKey = {
    val converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter
    val keyPair = converter.getKeyPair(pemKeyPair)
    keyPair.getPrivate
  }
}
```